# javascript link to another javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want create an program using javascript, but i want my file be more organize, is there some way that i can implement the concept of include or require of php. example: javascript file that only contains function let say function.js, then another javascript file main.js. is there a way that in main.js i can call a function in the function.js?

function.js

---

```
function test(){
   alert("hello world");
}
```

---

main.js

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    test();
});
```

---

Comment: just do what you say, it works as you expect.

Comment: Yes this works. If you want structure you should look at jquery Plugins: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/ and create your own plugin (seperate structure from implementation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can always use functions out of another javascript file.

though if you executed the code immediately you need to specify the right order: First the function definition, then the function call so:

```
<head>
    <script src="javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Not per see because document ready will be called after all hole DOM is loaded (and all javascript) (if javascript added in header)

Comment: @joelharkes — The timing of ready events doesn't seem relevant to the answer.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks what I think too, just the structure is important for the OP